# Play button not functioning

Tags: python-3.x

In my Alien Invasion game, everything works fine until I click the play button.
When I click it, I get this error:

```
    game_functions.py, line 45, in check_events
        check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)
    TypeError: check_play_button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mouse_y'
```

Here is the part of game_functions where the error is located:

```
def check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, bullets):
"""Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        check_keyup_events(event, ai_settings, ship)
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # Here is the error.
        check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)
        
def check_play_button(stats, play, button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    """Start a new game when the player clicks Play."""
    if play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
        stats.game_active = True
```

'mouse_y' is in check_play_button, but it is saying that it's missing.
I also don't see any spelling errors so I don't know what the problem is.
if any more code is needed, I will gladly provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `check_play_button` takes 5 parameters

```
def check_play_button(stats, play, button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
```

But you are sending 4

```
check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)
```

It should be like

```
check_play_button(stats, ???, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)
```

Comment: oh! I accidentally made play_button two different parameters. Thanks. I was really confused